# Fade in Fade out animation using CSS or Bootstrap Animation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations

When user selects an answer for a question, I need to display the result with CSS / (Bootstrap) animations.

1. I need to **Fade in the result** after a slight delay, and later **Fade  out the whole question** after waiting for 3 seconds.

CODE: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7zmsat?file=src/app/app.component.html

Note: I am suing Bootstrap as well.

HTML

```
<a (click)="checkAnswer(1)">Elephant</a> <br>
<a (click)="checkAnswer(2)">GOAT</a><br>
<a (click)="checkAnswer(13)">Crow</a>
<br>
<br><br>


<div class="slideRight" *ngIf="flag == false">
  CORRECT
</div>
<div class="slideRight" *ngIf="flag == true">
  INCORRECT
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slideRight {
  animation-name: slideRight;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideRight;
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  visibility: visible !important;
  /* New code here: */
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-150%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

TS

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  flag : boolean |undefined;

  checkAnswer(select : number){
    if (select === 1 ||select === 2 ) {
      this.flag = true;

    } else {
      this.flag = false;

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the default css position of the element correctly because you have setted the position in its place, so you need to put whats inside the animation inside the element props

```
 .slideRight {
     transform: translateX(-150%);
}
```

this will remove the glitch that i've seen when i opened your fiddle.